# Can we use both .NET Core v1.1 and v2.0 on windows Server IIS

Tags: iis, asp.net-core, windows-server-2012

We are currently hosting several Asp Net CORE v1.1 websites on a windows server 2012, IIS 8.5

I'm wondering if I can update .net core runtime to 2.0 and keep my v1.1 websites running without any modification.

I found no article on how to update the server environment safely.

The final goal would be to host both v1.1 and 2.0 asp core websites.

So question is, can I install  [.NET Core Windows Server Hosting bundle v2.0](https://aka.ms/dotnetcore.2.0.0-windowshosting) safely?
Or does anyone found an article about how to proceed?

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/features/blob/master/features/netcore/side-by-side.md

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. I have on my server applications running 1.0.5, 1.1.0 and 2.0.0 and they all work perfectly. When you install the Windows Server Hosting Bundle it just adds the new version runtime, as shown on the screen capture I uploaded.

They only thing I had to troubleshoot was an issue with the application pool.

[image: DotNet versions]